# How to access the string parameters in job dsl

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm passing the template job as well as the SVN Branch URL as string parameters to the job-dsl script. (Using the Parameterized build option).

```
def template = "${template_job}"
def url = "${svn_url}"
job('example') {
  using('template')
 configure { node ->
    node / scm / branches / 'hudson.scm.SubversionSCM_-ModuleLocation' / name('url')
  }
}
```

but I'm facing the error like:

```
Processing provided DSL script
ERROR: (script, line 1) No signature of method: script.$() is applicable for argument types: (script$_run_closure1) values: [script$_run_closure1@79b72972]
Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), run(), run(), any(), job(java.lang.String), any(groovy.lang.Closure)
```

Any suggestions how to access the string parameters in the job-dsl ? Thanks.

Comment: @daspilker : Any suggestions please. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to wrap the parameters in strings. They are already strings. If your parameters are `template_job` and `svn_url`, this should work:

```
job('example') {
  using(template_job)
  configure { node ->
    node / scm / branches / 'hudson.scm.SubversionSCM_-ModuleLocation' / name(svn_url)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! . With my current code I'm not able to change the Subversion "Repository URL" value for the new job . It's still pointing to the template jobs SVN URL.
I'm currently passing the new SVN URL as the string parameter via the build with Parameters option. 
Really looking forward for your suggestions. THnaks

My Jenkins version - 2.3.1

Comment: Another option is to reference the parameter as `"${template_job}"`.